# How to convert an entire table into JSON?

Tags: c#, json

I have some data stored on client side which I need to fetch thru JSON. Right now I am creating classes from my data and then converting these to JSON to send over the network. Is there any way to directly convert the entire table into JSON?

Comment: How are you creating classes from your data, and converting those classes into JSON? Most likely you can combine the two to go directly without a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

You have to retrieve each element's value and construct the JSON data.